# JWT How to bypass certain API routes and http methods

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt, json-web-token

I can make get JSON-Web-Token to ignore paths using .unless like this.

```
app.use(expressJWT({secret: config.JWTSECRET}).unless({path: 
['/register', 
'/authentication',
]}));
```

I have a route with different HTTP methods (get, put, post, delete). I want the GET version of /events to not require a token, but the POST version of /event to require a token. Can I do this without having different routes for GET and POST etc.

```
/events //GET - no token required
/events //POST - token required
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I know right, the express-jwt module is using `express-unless` to give you `.unless` method. With that, you can use a custom function to filter the request.

```
var filter = function(req) {return true;}
app.use(expressJWT({ secret: config.JWTSECRET}).unless(filter));
```

In the `filter` function, you can check the route (`req.path`) and the request type (`req.method`).

Answer (score 0):

```
 jwt({ secret, algorithms: ['HS256'] }).unless({
        path: [
            { url: /api/products, methods: ['GET', 'OPTIONS'] },
            { url: /api/categories/, methods: ['POST', 'OPTIONS'] },
           
        ]
    })
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.